# service postgres not running in docker

Tags: python, django, linux, postgresql, docker

I want to change my project Django with postgres to docker and then I make Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.0-slim-buster

ENV APP_HOME=/app
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  && apt-get install -y gettext \
  && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql \
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt




COPY ./docker/local/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint


ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint"]
```

my docker-compoae.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    api:
        container_name: estate-api-container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/local/django/Dockerfile
        command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
            - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - db
        

    db:
        container_name: estate-db-postgres12
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    postgres_data:
```

entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "estate1" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $POSTGRES_HOST $POSTGRES_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

when I run the command `docker-compose build` successfully build,
my problem when I run `docker-compose up`

this his logs

```
Creating network "estate-src_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "estate-src_static_volume" with default driver
Creating volume "estate-src_media_volume" with default driver
Creating volume "estate-src_postgres_data" with default driver
Pulling db (postgres:12.0-alpine)...
12.0-alpine: Pulling from library/postgres
89d9c30c1d48: Pull complete
66ddea140797: Pull complete
977cf4e465c1: Pull complete
ba931f945c10: Pull complete
7b61205fe7a7: Pull complete
2beee0482414: Pull complete
c2d37df49a3b: Pull complete
8c44ef2c13b8: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5115ec0afd378e91b5eed848a7e0ae0a9c7995fe05ad14f1eb3038bcf53acbf7
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:12.0-alpine
Creating estate-db-postgres12 ... done
Creating estate-api-container ... done
Attaching to estate-db-postgres12, estate-api-container
estate-db-postgres12 | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
estate-db-postgres12 | This user must also own the server process.
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
estate-db-postgres12 | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
estate-db-postgres12 | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | Data page checksums are disabled.
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
estate-db-postgres12 | creating subdirectories ... ok
estate-db-postgres12 | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
estate-db-postgres12 | selecting default max_connections ... 100
estate-db-postgres12 | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
estate-db-postgres12 | selecting default time zone ... UTC
estate-db-postgres12 | creating configuration files ... ok
estate-db-postgres12 | running bootstrap script ... ok
estate-db-postgres12 | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... sh: locale: not found
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:21.083 UTC [27] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
estate-db-postgres12 | ok
estate-db-postgres12 | syncing data to disk ... ok
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | Success. You can now start the database server using:
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
estate-db-postgres12 | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
estate-db-postgres12 | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
estate-db-postgres12 | waiting for server to start....2022-02-12 14:14:24.624 UTC [31] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 8.3.0) 8.3.0, 64-bit
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:24.741 UTC [31] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:25.010 UTC [32] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-12 14:14:21 UTC
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:25.074 UTC [31] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
estate-db-postgres12 |  done
estate-db-postgres12 | server started
estate-db-postgres12 | CREATE DATABASE
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | waiting for server to shut down....2022-02-12 14:14:25.799 UTC [31] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:25.829 UTC [31] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:25.830 UTC [31] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 38) exited with exit code 1
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:25.831 UTC [33] LOG:  shutting down
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.059 UTC [31] LOG:  database system is shut down
estate-db-postgres12 |  done
estate-db-postgres12 | server stopped
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
estate-db-postgres12 | 
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.145 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 8.3.0) 8.3.0, 64-bit
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.145 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.146 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.235 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
estate-api-container | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.381 UTC [42] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-12 14:14:26 UTC
estate-db-postgres12 | 2022-02-12 14:14:26.416 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
estate-api-container | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
estate-api-container | Traceback (most recent call last):
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
estate-api-container |     self.connect()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
estate-api-container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
estate-api-container |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
estate-api-container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
estate-api-container |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
estate-api-container |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
estate-api-container | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
estate-api-container |  Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
estate-api-container | 
estate-api-container | 
estate-api-container | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
estate-api-container | 
estate-api-container | Traceback (most recent call last):
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
estate-api-container |     self.run()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
estate-api-container |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
estate-api-container |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 127, in inner_run
estate-api-container |     self.check_migrations()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 505, in check_migrations
estate-api-container |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
estate-api-container |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
estate-api-container |     self.build_graph()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 223, in build_graph
estate-api-container |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
estate-api-container |     if self.has_table():
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
estate-api-container |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
estate-api-container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in cursor
estate-api-container |     return self._cursor()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 246, in _cursor
estate-api-container |     self.ensure_connection()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
estate-api-container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in ensure_connection
estate-api-container |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
estate-api-container |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
estate-api-container |     self.connect()
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
estate-api-container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
estate-api-container |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
estate-api-container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
estate-api-container |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
estate-api-container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
estate-api-container |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
estate-api-container | django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
estate-api-container |  Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

and then I try to change ports in `5433:5433` in my docker-compose.yml the result is the same as logs

if I running without docker no problem
any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: You need to change something in your application configuration to point to the database container (see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation: using the Compose service name `db` as a host name and the standard PostgreSQL port 5432, ignoring `ports:`).  Do you have that in your application configuration somewhere?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong,  this is just an API application with Django and PostgreSQL so I assumed no need for `networking in compose`
for your information, this is my first-time using docker so I haven't configuration somewhere

Comment: Where do you tell Django what the database driver and host name are?

Comment: ```POSTGRES_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
POSTGRES_DB=estate1
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432```

something is wrong??

Comment: You should make sure your .env files contains the correct settings for django to connect to the database inside the container and the host needs to be "db" if you publish your settings.py (just the database bit) we can check if it is correct.

Comment: I tell Django database in .env the result as same any suggestion

Comment: and I am sure contains .env files correct

Comment: The last two lines in the log very clearly indicate that your Django app thinks the database is running in the same container ('locally'). It isn't and you need to change the definition in the Django app of where it can find the database.

Comment: solved
Thanks for your advice @Hans Kilian